# Admob issue with proguard

Tags: android, crash, runtime, admob, proguard

Im getting a crash when running the app with proguard. This is happening on Admob. Im using Admob 6.

Stacktrace:
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.ads.internal.AdWebView.setWebViewClient
    at com.google.ads.internal.d.a(SourceFile:311)
    at com.google.ads.internal.d.(SourceFile:285)
    at com.google.ads.AdView.a(SourceFile:538)
    at com.google.ads.AdView.(SourceFile:91)

I have also added these to my proguard.cfg with no luck:

## Admob

```
-dontwarn com.google.ads.** 

-keep public class com.google.ads.** {*;}


-keep public class com.google.gson.** {
    public protected *;
}

-keep public class com.google.ads.internal.** {*;} 
-keep public class com.google.ads.internal.AdWebView.** {*;} 
-keep public class com.google.ads.internal.state.AdState {*;} 
-keep public class com.google.ads.mediation.** {*;} 
-keep public class com.google.ads.mediation.adfonic.** {*;} 
-keep public class com.google.ads.mediation.admob.** {*;} 
-keep public class com.google.ads.mediation.adfonic.util.** {*;} 
-keep public class com.google.ads.mediation.customevent.** {*;} 
-keep public class com.google.ads.searchads.** {*;} 
-keep public class com.google.ads.util.** {*;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found out why. I left my own version of the WebViewClient on the project when I packaged it. As soon as I removed it the issue went away.